# new controller mistake Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I was testing out while learning Laravel 5, creating a new controller, but I do get a strange error, when it is supposed to work fine. Here it is:

I created a new folder **Pages** in the **app/Http/Controllers/** directory, and added the controller **ContactController** into it:
*app/Http/Controllers/ContactController.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Pages;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ContactController extends Controller {

    public function getIndex() {
        return 'This is the Contact page.';
    }
}
```

and then I created a route in the **routes/web** file:
*routes/web.php*

```
Route::controller('contact', 'Pages\ContactController');
```

Strangely, when I access the **/contact** URL -> http://laravel.devpeaks.com/public/contact, I get:
BadMethodCallException in compiled.php line 6271:
Method controller does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should adjust your nginx/apache config in a way that root directory is pointed to /public.
2. `Route::controller` is deprecated since Laravel-5.2. You should use `Route::resource` and name rename the method from getIndex to index. If you use Laravel-5.1 implement the first point only.

Comment: Just curious, why is this answer better than mine? I mean it was posted 11 minutes later and repeats exactly what I wrote...

Answer (score 2):

[`Route::controller()` was deprecated in 5.2 and was removed in 5.3](https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0). Try this route instead:

```
Route::resource('contact', 'Pages\ContactController');
```

Then run `php artisan route:list` command to make sure all routes exists.

Also, you should fix web server settings by pointing it to `public` directory instead of Laravel project root. After doing this use normal URLs like `domain.com/contact`.